# perl "eq" doesn't work well. I can't found my fault

Tags: perl

I'm writting a small server with perl. There is some small problem. When the client give me a sentence like this "op:xxx:xxx:xxx", I'll get op. then do things depending on what op is. It works will if the op is adduser and so on. (I use if $op eq "adduser"...)
    But when I get a "getList:xxx:xxx" and I have get the $op = getList, it can't pass it like "if $op eq "getList"". I know, it must be my mistake. But I just can't find it. 
   thank you for everyone.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package MyPackage;
use base qw(Net::Server);
our %data_base;
our %tag_base;
sub list {
    my %resault;
    foreach ( keys %tag_base) {
        print STDERR $_ . "1";
        my @tags = split /:/, $tag_base{$_};
        foreach ( @tags) {
            $resault{$_} ++;
        }
    }
    my @tags;
    foreach ( keys %resault) {
        push @tags, "$_,$resault{$_}";
    }
    $_ = join ";", @tags;
    print ;
    print STDERR ;
}

sub users {
    my $topic = shift;
    my @users;
    foreach ( keys %tag_base) {
        push @users, $_ if $tag_base{$_} =~ /$topic/;
    }
    $_ = join ";", @users;
    print ;
}

sub process_request {
    my $self = shift;
    my $person;
    my @info;
    while (<STDIN>) {
        my @gets = split /:/, $_;
        print STDERR "@gets\n";
        # $data_base{shift @person} = join ":", @person;
        my $op = shift @gets;
        $op =~ s/\s//;
        print STDERR $op . "\n";
        if (  $op eq "adduser") {
            my $user_name = shift @gets;
            if ( exists $data_base{$user_name}) {
                print "already_exist";
            } else {
                $data_base{$user_name} = join ":", @gets;
                print "addUserSu";
            }            
        } elsif ( $op eq "login") {
            my $login_name = shift @gets;
            my $login_pw   = shift @gets;
            if ( defined $data_base{$login_name}) {
                $person = $data_base{$login_name};
                @info   = split /:/, $person;
                $info[0] =~ s/\s+//;
                if ($login_pw eq $info[0]) {
                    print "$person";
                } else {
                    print "/$info[0]/";
                }
            } else {
                print "unexist_user";
            }
        } elsif ( $op eq "addTag") {
            my $tag_user = shift @gets;
            $tag_base{$tag_user} = join ":", @gets;
            print "addTagSu";
        } elsif ( $op eq "getList") {
            print STDERR "right";
            &list;
        } elsif ( $op eq "getUsers") {
            &users;
        }
    }
}

MyPackage->run(port => 13800);
```

Comment: What do you mean "can't pass it like "if $op eq "getList""... Whats the error?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.  Are you getting any error messages?  If not, are you getting any unexpected output?  If so, please give us sample input along with the corresponding expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see two (simple) reasons this might fail:

```
$op =~ s/\s//;
```

You only remove one whitespace: The first one. If your intention is to strip all whitespace, you'd want `s/\s+//g`.

And second:

Random capital letters in strings, variable names and commands is Evil. `eq` is case sensitive, so if `$op` is `"getlist"`, then `if ($op eq "getList")` will be false. Unless capitalization is important to you, you could do `if (lc($op) eq "getlist")`.

Without sample input, expected output and actual output, this is however nothing more than guesswork.

Also, as a debug statement, this is useless:

```
print STDERR $op . "\n";
```

That is easily confused and overlooked. For example, if `$op` is empty, it just produces a blank line in your error log. Use:

```
print STDERR "OP is: '$op'\n";
```

Now you will be able to identify the line where `$op` should appear, and you will be more easily see whitespace surrounding it.

Comment: The whitespace removal is probably the problem. He should change his warn to `print STDERR qq{'$op'\n};` and see what is actually being sent.

Comment: @gpojd I know, I just added that. =P

Answer (score 1):

You are reading strings without chomping them.

i.e.

When you run your code :

```
addtag:fred:barney
```

The input is stored as `fred => "barney\n"`

when you `getList`, the output is :

```
barney
,1;
```

I suspect the client is expecting 1 line of output that reads :

```
barney,1;
```

So, just add a chomp in your code here :

```
while (<STDIN>) {
        chomp;
        my @gets = split /:/, $_;
```